# Second modal is preventing the close button from working all modals?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm having this issue where I have two modals and was going to add a third one, each opens up correctly when the button is clicked on but neither of them close when the "X" is clicked. If I click off the screen it automatically closes. Can't figure out why it's doing that since both have separate ids. If I remove the Second Modal JS code it works fine, but then I can't open the second modal window.

Here is the HTML:

```
   <div id="generic_price_table">   
        <div>
                    <div class="row-2 clearfix">
                         <div class="col-1-2">
                            <div class="generic_content clearfix">
                                <div class="generic_head_price clearfix">
                                    <div class="generic_head_content clearfix">
                                        <div class="head_bg"></div>
                                        <div class="head">
                                            <span></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="generic_price_tag clearfix">    
                                    </div>
                                </div>                            
                                <div class="generic_feature_list">
                                    <ul>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="generic_price_btn clearfix">
                                    <a id="myBtn" class="" href="javascript:void(0)">Register</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>   
                        </div>
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                          <!-- Modal content -->
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                <h1>Register</h1>
                                <p><strong>Select one of the below options to Start a Team, Join a Team, or Register as an Individual. </strong></p>
                                <p>
                                    <a class="modalReg" id="StartTeamBTN" href="">Start a Team</a> <br />
                                    <a class="modalReg" id="JoinTeamBTN" href="">Join a Team</a> <br />
                                    <a class="modalRegRight" id="RegisterIndividualBTN" href="">Register as an Individual</a> <br />
                                </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      <div class="col-1-2">
                            <div class="generic_content clearfix">
                                <div class="generic_head_price clearfix">
                                    <div class="generic_head_content clearfix">
                                        <div class="head_bg"></div>
                                        <div class="head">
                                            <span></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="generic_price_tag clearfix">    
                                    </div>
                                </div>                            
                                <div class="generic_feature_list">
                                    <ul>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="generic_price_btn clearfix">
                                    <a id="myBtn_2" class="" href="javascript:void(0)">Register</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>                               
                        </div>
                  </div>                   
                </div>

                 <div id="myModal_2" class="modal">

                   <!-- Modal content -->
                     <div class="modal-content">
                       <span class="close">&times;</span>
                          <h1>Register</h1>
                           <p><strong>Select one of the below options to Start a Team, Join a Team, or Register as an Individual. </strong></p>
                            <p>
                             <a class="modalReg" id="StartTeamBTN" href="">Start a Team</a> <br />
                             <a class="modalReg" id="">Join a Team</a> <br />
                             <a class="modalRegRight" id="">Register as an Individual</a> <br />
                            </p>
                      </div>
                </div>             
        </div>
```

And this the js that I'm using from W3S:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}


// Get the second modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal_2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn_2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

here it is in jsbin: [JSBIN LINK](http://jsbin.com/dohasaduya/edit?html,css,js,output)

Really appreciate any suggestions/help!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. you're using same variable names for both modals this leads to your 1st modal variables (btn and modal) to be overwritten by 2nd modal variables. So your 1st button opens 2nd modal
2. you use 1st modal close button (document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]) as selector for your 2nd span close button so it attempts to close 1st modal instead of 2nd
3. same thing with closing modal on window.onclick. it closes 2nd modal (see #1 above) not 1st one. there's a conflict between your onclick functions

You can try this as a quick fix:

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9nv3vqdd/1/

```
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
}


// Get the second modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal_2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn_2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}


// Get the second modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal_2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn_2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if ((event.target == modal1) || (event.target == modal2)) {

        event.target.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9nv3vqdd/1/

Comment: Hi thank you for the solution! your explanation makes it more clear as to why I was having the issue. I completely forgot that I needed to adjust for the variable names as well. The clarification of the onclick issue is awesome, didn't think that was creating any conflicts. thanks Olenka! really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

In your js file, change your secondary modal id names and make them unique.

```
// Get the second modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal_2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn_2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
  console.log('here');
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```